# Fragment portion of @Html.ActionLink overloaded method to link to a part of the page that is tabbed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC web application.

On one of my pages I have tabbed the information that looks like this:

[Tabbed Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJDP9.png)

My ActionLink looks like this:

`@Html.ActionLink("Back to Details", "RecordView", "ApplicantRecords", null, null, "Documents", new { id = Model.InternID }, null)`

Now when I hover over the link in my application it has the correct syntax with the InternID and fragment but when I click on it.. it sends me to the Tab that says "Applicant Profile", not "Documents"..

When I hover over the "Documents" tab it has the same url as when I hover my actionlink in my application.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is `RecordView` your action method which shows all three tabs ? Where do you have the link "Back to details" ?

Comment: Record View is indeed the action that I am redirecting to on the ApplicantRecords controller.

Comment: You did not answer my quetion yet. Where is your "back to details" link ? Which page(Action) has all your 3 tabs ?

Comment: The action that has all 3 of my tabs is the RecordView action.. the "back to details" link is in the cshtml of the "Edit" view on my Documents controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Chris Patt's answer.

You need to explicitly enable the specific tab you want.

First you need to pass one more param in your url querystring to represent which tab to be selected.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Details", "RecordView", "ApplicantRecords", 
                                       new { id = Model.InternID ,tab="documents" }, null)
```

and in your `RecordView()` action method, you will accept this, set it to ViewBag so that you can read it in your razor view.

```
public ActionResult RecordView(int id,string tab="profile")
{ 
  ViewBag.CurrentTab = tab;
  return View();
}
```

and in your view, on the document `ready` event , we will read this value and use that to show a specific tab.

```
$(function() {

    var tab = "@ViewBag.CurrentTab";
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+tab+']').tab('show');

});
```

Assuming your tab link's href values are `"#profile"` and `"#documents"`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
       <a href="#profile" aria-controls="Profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
   </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#documents" aria-controls="documents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Docs</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so here is my actionlink  now:   `@Html.ActionLink("Back to Details", "RecordView", "ApplicantRecords", new { id = Model.InternID, tab="Documents" }, null)` ... my action is now `public ActionResult RecordView(int? id, string tab="Details")
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentTab = tab;` ... in my view I have added          <script>
        $(function () {
            var tab = "@ViewBag.CurrentTab";
            $('.nav-tabs a[href=#' + tab + ']').tab('show');
        });
    </script>

Comment: for some reason my line breaks arent' working.. sorry for the congestion... but my tabs link's href values  are:  `<ul class="nav nav-tabs marginTabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Details" data-toggle="tab">Applicant Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Notes" data-toggle="tab">Notes <span class="badge">@Model.InternNotes.Where(x => x.deleted == false).Count()</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Documents" data-toggle="tab">Documents <span class="badge">@Model.InternDocs.Where(x => x.deleted == false).Count()</span></a></li>
        </ul>`

Comment: also I can't seem to get my code in code blocks.. only inline single lines are working

Comment: So change the `Html.ActionLink` method to match with your Id's (change `documents` to `Documents` ( **It is case sensitive**)

Comment: in my actionlink... I did capitalize Documents.. just like the ID.. now when I hover over that link it is : ApplicantRecords/RecordView/15?tab=Documents... but still sends me back to the "Applicant Profile" tab.. not the Documents tab

Comment: am I going to have add another javascript function if I want to go to Notes tab?

Comment: No. The current code is good for all the tabs as long as you pass the correct `tab` parameter value properly to the action method. Make sure you do not have any other js errors in your page.

Comment: Ahh I have a custom folder for scripts and I rendered that folder on my RecordView view... and in that folder was something that I tried to put together from my research on this problem which was causing the redirection error! Thank you so much for your help! if my reputation was higher everyone could see the upvote.. but anyways thanks again. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply appending the fragment to the URL doesn't do anything to activate a particular tab. JavaScript "tab" libraries merely utilize fragments for graceful degradation: if JavaScript is not enabled, clicking the "tab" will jump you to the right portion of the page where the tab content lies, because of the way page anchors work. However, you are responsible to inspecting the fragment in the URL, if it exists, and activating the appropriate tab. How to activate the tab depends on your particular solution, which you haven't given us any information about, though.

Comment: ok so when I click on my "back to details" link.. it needs to activate the "Documents" tab. what do you need to see that can help me activate the tabs?

Comment: thanks to you and @Shyju I was able to get this working. thank you for the advice